# get total view of profile views?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

so i have this table which contains: username,viewer,views. and i have two columns which is:  [image]

now what i did is a function known as :

```
public function TotalView($username)
        {
    $sql = "SELECT views from profile_views where username=:username";
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
    $paramaters = [':username' => $username];
    $stmt->execute($paramaters);
    $count = $stmt->columnCount();
    return $count;

}
```

now it says Views:1 in the profile page. is there anything i'm doing wrong?
EDIT: user saty has fixed it. i should of used $count = $stmt->rowCount();.
instead of columnCount();

Comment: Instead of `columnCount` USE `rowCount()`

Comment: @saty omfg i feel so dumb thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[columnCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.columncount.php)

> Returns the number of columns in the result set

SO instead use

[rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last SQL statement

```
$stmt->execute($paramaters);
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
```

OR

You can use

```
$stmt->execute($paramaters);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
$count = count($rows);
return $count;
```

Comment: thanks but pdo doc says  rowCount() shouldn't be used for select statement looks like i was confused

Comment: Use can use `$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
$num_rows = count($rows);`